# How can I fill a google form with IFTTT

Tags: autofill, ifttt

I have a google form I have to fill every day with the same info.

Whats the best way to text a number and then automatically fill the form?

What do I use for scanning the web page and filling the form?

Comment: Forum or form? Form is in the title and forum is repeated in the body of the question.

Comment: I meant form, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google lets you send the form URL with pre-filled answers. The directions below are from [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en&visit_id=1-636244958026962795-4261577190&rd=1).

- Open a form in Google Forms.
- In the top right, click More
- Choose Get pre-filled link.
- Fill in any answer fields you want to pre-populate.
- Click Submit.
- To send the pre-populated form to
  respondents, copy and send the link at the top.

If it's not your form, you can still do this but it's a bit more hassle.

You'll need to figure out the form entry ids by viewing the page source.

In this [example form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfcOpri8vqdMan2j2_FZNMEEf7M-nj-XZ_duLOwxKFQDT95gw/viewform?usp=sf_link), we'd be able to fill out the two form elements with the following URL.

[https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfcOpri8vqdMan2j2_FZNMEEf7M-nj-XZ_duLOwxKFQDT95gw/viewform?entry.317303506=answer+one&entry.1178107516=b](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfcOpri8vqdMan2j2_FZNMEEf7M-nj-XZ_duLOwxKFQDT95gw/viewform?entry.317303506=answer%20one&entry.1178107516=b)

You can figure out the entry ids by viewing source like the image below.[image: view source to find entry id]

`entry.317303506` then becomes `?entry.317303506=answer+one` to fill out that element, the next piece `&entry.1178107516=b` selects  option **b**.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to get all the entry numbers and the link. Now how can i make it automatic so when i text a specific number a server executes it for me.

Comment: I need the same thing, to fill a form on IFTTT trigger, it is not clear what should be done after i have found the entry numbers/values.